# Grails SOAP request with httpbuilder throws SAXParseException

Tags: grails, soap

when I post a Soap request with HttpBuilder, I get an exception.
My Code:

```
def reqxml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
            "  <soapenv:Header/>\n" +
            "  <soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "    <web:GetWeather xmlns:web=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET\">\n" +
            "      <web:CityName>Berlin</web:CityName>\n" +
            "      <web:CountryName>Germany</web:CountryName>\n" +
            "    </web:GetWeather>\n" +
            "  </soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>"
def http = new HTTPBuilder("http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL")

http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.XML) {
    body = reqxml
    response.success = { resp, xml ->
        println (xml)
    }
    response.failure = {resp, xml ->
        println "Error"
    }
}
```

This code throws a SAXParseException with the message Content is not allowed in prolog.
Happens at the http.request method.